# Linux module blacklist GUI

Tags: linux, kernel-module, blacklist

Is there a GUI like application that lists all the kernel modules that are inserted at boot-time, with a little description and with an option to remove them?

P.S. I'm aware of the manual mode with the blacklist config file and lsmod command (and of course googling each module name).

Answer (score 0):

You can change the services started at boot with the help of [BUM](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/bum).

Install it: `sudo apt-get install bum`.

Run: `sudo bum`.

[image]

Uncheck the box and click "Apply".

Comment: By modules I was referring to kernel modules. Sorry for misleading you. I've updated my post.